# problem with placement of a legend on a pie chart still remains

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, pie-chart

I have a problem with the legend on a pie chart, I already received help from here but it still doesn't work as I hoped (i don't have the entire legend on there, the frame of the legend is partly outside it) and I don't know why. Here is what I get when running the following code :  [image: Here is the plot I get]

Here is my code :

```
 pie1_PGS <- pie1_PGS[!(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021 == 0),]

 lab <- paste0(round(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021/sum(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021) * 100, 2), 
          "%")

 library(plotrix)
 pie3D(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021, 
  radius = 0.75,
  height = 0.1,
  theta = 0.7,
  border = "white",
  col = rainbow(length(lab)),
  shade = 0.5,
  labels = lab,
  labelcol = "red",
  labelcex = 0.75,
  explode = 0.2,
  main = "Répartition des séjours 2021 par type") 
legend(0.5, 1.1, pie1_PGS$type_de_sejour, cex = 0.3, fill = rainbow(length(lab)))
```

Here is my dataset :

```
structure(list(type_de_sejour = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("Ambulatoires", 
"Externes", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé"), class = "factor"), nb_sejours_2021 = c(20794, 
365, 7866)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use "topright" and the argument `inset` to inset distance from the margin like this:

```r
pie1_PGS <- structure(list(type_de_sejour = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("Ambulatoires", 
                                                                                "Externes", "Fictifs", "Hospitalisé"), class = "factor"), nb_sejours_2021 = c(20794, 
                                                                                                                                                              365, 7866)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L), class = "data.frame")

pie1_PGS <- pie1_PGS[!(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021 == 0),]

lab <- paste0(round(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021/sum(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021) * 100, 2), 
              "%")

library(plotrix)
pie3D(pie1_PGS$nb_sejours_2021, 
      radius = 0.75,
      height = 0.1,
      theta = 0.7,
      border = "white",
      col = rainbow(length(lab)),
      shade = 0.5,
      labels = lab,
      labelcol = "red",
      labelcex = 0.75,
      explode = 0.2,
      main = "Répartition des séjours 2021 par type") 
legend("topright", legend = pie1_PGS$type_de_sejour, cex = 0.3, fill = rainbow(length(lab)), inset = 0.05)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>